# How to round up to the next hundred in Java

Tags: java, android, integer

I want to make digital store similar e-commerce and then I want to round an int to the next highest multiple of 100 in Java (Android Studio) for example:

782->800

9876->9900

7987->8000

24523->24600

123412->123500
etc....

for this, i have some code to handle this, but sometimes i got some bugs, this is my code on java

```
    private int fee = 200;
private int getRoundedPrice(int i){
    int amount = i + fee;
    int roundedAmount = 0;
    if(amount < 10000){
        roundedAmount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amount).charAt(0) + "000");
    }else if(amount < 100000){
        roundedAmount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amount).substring(0,2) + "000");
    }else if(amount < 1000000){
        roundedAmount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amount).substring(0,3) + "000");
    }else if(amount < 10000000){
        roundedAmount = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amount).substring(0,4) + "000");
    }
    return roundedAmount + rounding(amount-roundedAmount);
}

private int rounding(int amount){
    if(amount < 100){
        return 100;
    }else if(amount < 200){
        return 200;
    }else if(amount < 300){
        return 300;
    }else if(amount < 400){
        return 400;
    }else if(amount < 500){
        return 500;
    }else if(amount < 600){
        return 600;
    }else if(amount < 700){
        return 700;
    }else if(amount < 800){
        return 800;
    }else if(amount < 900){
        return 900;
    }else if(amount < 1000){
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

using this code, sometimes it works but sometimes this make bugs, for example:

123141->12400 (i experienced it)

i don't understand where the problem but i think this code is not good(i mean not stable), maybe others can help me to give more better codesolution for this problem... thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
int processed = (int)(Math.ceil(input/100.0)*100);
```